# custom codeigniter config

Tags: php, codeigniter

in the folder config i've created a file called validation_rules.php
the file looks like this: (short version)

```
$form_registration = array(
        array(
            'field' => 'language',
            'label' => 'language',
            'rules' => 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'email',
            'label' => 'email',
            'rules' => 'required|valid_email'
        ));
```

i then read somewhere that i need to load it like this for the form validator

```
$this->ci->load->config('validation_rules', TRUE);
$this->form_validation->set_rules($form_registration);
```

but i get an error, am i doing it right?
this is the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function config() on a non-object in
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html):

> Note: If you do create your own config files use the same format as
> the primary one, storing your items in an array called $config.
> CodeIgniter will intelligently manage these files so there will be no
> conflict even though the array has the same name (assuming an array
> index is not named the same as another).

Try wrapping your arrays inside a $config array